# Use string from Java in Jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a string variable in my Java application that is being built by Jenkins. After Jenkins build is done, it sends a notification to our internal messenger. I need to include this Java string into the notification message. This string is not constant. It is dynamic and depends on the response that is being returned by a request that is handled in Java app.

Currently, the notification message consists of a build's metadata - status, build number, job name. These values are taken by Jenkins by getting the values of respective environment variables.

How can I get in Jenkins the value of the Java string variable?

Comment: What about expose an API in your java app and call it with a curl or something like this? Have you a declarative groovy pipeline in your Jenkins?

Comment: @dcalap I have a scripted pipeline running on a Windows host.
How would it work to expose an API and calling it within the pipeline?

Comment: Do you know how to create an API in a Java app? If yes, I can write an answer assuming this scenario.

Comment: Probably I know. I just can't understand yet the idea how to do it and in which for the API should be exposed.

Comment: Ok, that's how I understand your problem. You need to send a String to a messenger, and this String depends on your Jenkins build data. Then you need to send this Jenkins build data in a request to a Java app and this app creates a response with the final String and sends it to the messenger, is that correct?

Comment: No, not really correct. Jenkins doesn't send anything to the Java app. The Java app itself sends a POST request to a 3rd service, gets the response and parse it. One of the values parsed from the response needs to be exposed to the Jenkins so that Jenkins could send this response value to the messenger.

Answer (score 1):

According to our previuous comments, I guess you need to do something like this:

- Create an **API** in your Java App: this **API** needs to publish an operation with the parsed response (the one which gets the 3rd service response).
- Call this **API** from Jenkins, with, for example, a *curl* (you can do it with Groovy if you want to), something like this (assuming you return a json response):

  ```
  //The next http://yourdomain... URL is the one your Java app will expose with your parsed response
  def response = sh script: "curl 'http://yourdomain/api/v1/yourResource'", returnStdout: true
  def jsonProcessed = readJSON text: response

  //Do some post-process in Jenkins if you need to using readJSON. I just put a dummy raise error example (Check the readJSON link below)
  if (jsonProcessed.key == 'whatever') {
      error "Raise some error"
  }

  // Or directly the code to send the response to the messenger
  // TODO Your sending code HERE
  ```
- Send the response from Jenkins to your messenger.

[Help with readJSON](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After several other discussions, it turns out that writing a string in Java app to a file and then read that file within the Jenkins pipeline is the easiest solution. So I did.